# Socket.io threw err:fn.bind is not a function

Tags: mongoose, socket.io, nodes

I got the same error while trying to build the multiroom chat application from the book "Node.js in action"
why does it happen and how can I fix it ? please help ~

```
<MY_PATH>\chatapp\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\index.js:210
  if (fn) process.nextTick(fn.bind(null, null, sids));
                              ^

TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
    at Adapter.clients (<MY_PATH>\chatapp\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\index.js:210:31)
    at Namespace.clients (<MY_PATH>\chatapp\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:256:16)
    at updateUserList (<MY_PATH>\chatapp\socket\socket.js:49:41)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (<MY_PATH>\chatapp\socket\socket.js:22:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at <MY_PATH>\chatapp\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:514:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error related to the version of socket.io you are using. Make sure that in your package.json file, you set it to not use the latest version of the required dependencies, but rather to only specifically use the versions mentioned in the book.

Please refer to the following link for further information

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2428

Hope this helps !